# How to export Global Workflows with TFS REST Api?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

It is possible to upload global workflows by using UpdateWorkItemTypeDefinition(), but how can I export? ExportWorkItemTypeDefinition() seems only to work with WITs

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For exportWorkItemTypeDefinition() method, there are three Parameters for it:

> - project: string. Optional. Project ID or project name
> - type: string. Optional.
> - exportGlobalLists: boolean. Optional.

When you specify "project" and "type" to "null", the method will export the Global Workflow. And it will also export global lists when you set "exportGlobalLists" to "true".

Comment: And if I specify project but no type name I will get a "project"-level workflow?

Comment: @FerdiÖztürk No, it still return the collection level workflow as I test.

Comment: I succesfully tested to upload a workflow on project-level and showing (export) it again with my VSTS extension. Other projects of the same collection do not return that projects workflow. Seems to be project-level